# C code to parse out certain characters in a string

Tags: c, strings

I have the following code

```
int eval(char* string) {

char* token;

outputString[0] = NULL;

token = strtok(string, " ");

while(token != NULL){

   if(strstr((char *) token, "@") != NULL) {
      strcat(outputString, "@");
      token = calc(token);
   }
   strcat(outputString, token);
   strcat(outputString, " ");
   token = strtok(NULL, " "); 
}

 printf("%s\n", outputString);

}
```

It is called on a string that looks like this

```
The water has @TREE and @SKY in it.
```

This code works completely fine. However I want to make it more efficient.

The code is supposed to do the following --

Cut the string up by spaces, however, if an `@` is found, it should be sent away to be evaluated by `calc();`. If none are found, we continue splitting the string by spaces until one is actually found. While we are running through, we concatenate it onto outputString and continue forward.

Comment: How  `aaa@bbb` and similar tokens should be processed?

Answer (score 2):

- `outputString` doesn't have enough room to accomodate the results. It can hold just one byte. It is just unlucky coincidence that the code does not segfault. In any case, undefined behaviour.

  If the intention is just to print the result out, you don't need `outputString` at all. Just `printf` the tokens as you compute them.
- `strcat` must scan the entire `outputString` to figure out where it ends. The overall time complexity of the repeated `strcat`s becomes roughly quadratic. I recommend to maintain a pointer to the end of `outputString`, and `strcpy` the token.